# JMS resource not created

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I am trying out an example in "EJB3 in Action" (chapter 2 example) on Glassfish appserver and it has an MDB which fails to deploy with the error

```
JMS resource not created : OrderBillingQueue
```

I have created connection resources and destination resources as adviced in other posts but the error remains. Please help me fix this.

Here is the snapshot of the JMS resources created in glassfish
[image]

---

[image]

Relevant parts of the source code: the MDB

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationName", propertyValue="OrderBillingQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue")
        },mappedName = "OrderBillingQueue"
)
public class OrderBillingMDB implements MessageListener {
```

Relevant parts of the source code: the Resource Injection part

```
@Resource(name = "jms/QueueConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Resource(name = "jms/OrderBillingQueue", mappedName="OrderBillingQueue")
private Destination billingQueue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a glassfish-ejb-jar.xml file with following content seems to resolve the problem.

```
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
  <enterprise-beans>
      <ejb>
          <ejb-name>OrderBillingMDB</ejb-name>
          <jndi-name>jms/OrderBillingQueue</jndi-name>
      </ejb></enterprise-beans>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

But not sure why glassfish requires this.